# After click on QueryClose on Userform/runtime error in VBA , how to closed particular hidden excel file?

Tags: vba

I often make macros that retrieve information from files without showing them, by opening them in non-visible instances of excel, but if the macro stops in runtime they may remain open and take more resources.
Need to code that closed particular hidden excel file(in my case "Upload_Final.xlsm") , after ckick on QueryClose button on userform or runtime error.

Comment: Just add an [error handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/on-error-statement) to your macro.

Comment: i try with "On Error Resume Next" but it will not give error but Excel file remain hide .
Any suggestion how to make Excel file make visible or closed hidden Excel file on error .

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` instruction is used to "ignore" error as it's telling the compiler: "no matter of error -> proceed next line"... You need to use `On Error Goto HandlerNameHere`.